# How to set value of grep result to variable in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, grep

This line of code searches through a website, extracts and prints out a list of domain names to screen.   It works perfectly.

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)'
```

I need to set the result of this grep pattern match to a variable so that I can pipe the results to a mysql insert command.  Unfortunately, I can't even echo the variable to screen.  What am I doing wrong?

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | domain=“$(grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)’)” | echo $domain
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Wyatt

Comment: Your quotes look funny to me. Try fixing them and see if you get any further.

Comment: I have tried removing the quotes and I have tried back ticks.  Neither provide me a result.  Quotes and no quotes, nothing happens.  If I use back ticks, I get this error...  bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ domain=$(httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)')
$ echo "$domain"
```

You can wrap entire command including pipe into `$(..)` as you cannot pipe output of a command to command substitution.

Comment: Yes, this works, as it does set output value of grep to $domain variable as a big list of domains pulled from the httrack data stream.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get to my end solution from here.  I'm trying to extract the domains and insert them into a mysql database as grep finds them on the fly.  One domain per field in a table.  I was hoping to do all of this within one command line.  I'm stuck.  Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: @user3672303 As you have gotten one step closer, I would recommend closing this question and opening another one where you can explain the question more clearly under `sql` or `mysql` tags.